# VBA - Combine 2 xml files and sum values in output file

Tags: xml, vba

I have 2 XML files that I need to combine (append).
I have that part done with the help of another answer on here.

However, I also need to add 2 values in a field in the output file.
1st file has 32 packages and the other one has 7. The package count in the output file should be 32+7=39.
32 in 1st file, 7 in second.

I have written the below code to combine the 2 files. This is working fine. The second file is appended to the 1st file except the package count stays 32.

I want the xx to say 39 in the output file instead of 32. Can you please help me with this part. I am not familiar with XML at all.

```
Sub AppendXMLFiles()
'requires reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0'
'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
Dim file1 As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim file2 As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim appendNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim File1Path As String
Dim File2Path As String

'## Load xml files in to a DOM document'
File1Path = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xml*), *.xml*", , , , False)
File2Path = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xml*), *.xml*", , , , False)
file1.Load File1Path
file2.Load File2Path

'## iterate the childnodes of the second file, appending to the first file'
For Each appendNode In file2.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
    file1.DocumentElement.appendChild appendNode
Next

'## View the new XML in the immediate window'
'Debug.Print file1.XML

'## Write the combined file to a NEW file'
'   note: if the specified filepath already exists, this will overwrite it'
Dim Dfolder As FileDialog
Dim DFolderPath As String

Set Dfolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With Dfolder
    .Title = "Select Destination Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    DFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
fso.CreateTextFile(DFolderPath & "combined xml file.xml", True, False).Write file1.XML

Set file1 = Nothing
Set file2 = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Part of Input file 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><Manifest><Header><Version>3.2</Version><AccountNumber /><PackageCount>32</PackageCount><FileCreateDateTime>2020-09-15 15:09</FileCreateDateTime><TimeZone>GMT</TimeZone><Filename>MANIFEST-0009-123455678.XML</Filename></Header><Package>...Followed by details of packages like name, address, weight, cost, etc....><ProductDescriptionURL /><FTA /></Item></Package></Manifest>
```

Part of Input file 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><Manifest><Header><Version>3.2</Version><AccountNumber /><PackageCount>7</PackageCount><FileCreateDateTime>2020-09-15 15:09</FileCreateDateTime><TimeZone>GMT</TimeZone><Filename>MANIFEST-0009-91011121.XML</Filename></Header><Package>...Followed by details of packages like name, address, weight, cost, etc....<ProductDescriptionURL /><FTA>Y</FTA></Item></Package></Manifest>
```

Part of Output file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Manifest><Header><Version>3.2</Version><AccountNumber/><PackageCount>32</PackageCount><FileCreateDateTime>2020-09-15 15:09</FileCreateDateTime><TimeZone>GMT</TimeZone><Filename>MANIFEST-0009-00218355.XML</Filename></Header><Package>...Package Details of File 1 + Package Details of File 2...<ProductDescriptionURL/><FTA>Y</FTA></Item></Package></Manifest>
```

In the output file, I want the `<PackageCount>32</PackageCount>` to be `<PackageCount>39</PackageCount>`.

Comment: can you add the input and output xml files to your question? since you are copying nodes from file2 into file1 i assume that you will get 2 entries with a package count. one with 32 and one with 7. best way i think is to exclude the package count entry from your copy action. Then do a count of the nodes minus 1 as that is the file1 package count node. then with a linq or xpath expression find the package count node and update the value before saving it back to file.

Comment: Hi @martijn, I cannot add the whole input files as there is confidential data in it. I have added the start and end tags/modes in the edit though for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is an quick and dirty example in C# to get you started. it could be that the notation needs to be altered for VB, but I'm not an VB programmer. Looking at the Microsoft documentation VB and C# do not differ a lot when it comes to this.

```
var msg1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Manifest><Header><Version>3.2</Version><AccountNumber/><PackageCount>2</PackageCount><FileCreateDateTime>2020-09-15 15:09</FileCreateDateTime><TimeZone>GMT</TimeZone><Filename>MANIFEST-0009-123455678.XML</Filename></Header><Package><ProductDescriptionURL/><FTA/><Item/></Package><Package><ProductDescriptionURL/><FTA/><Item/></Package></Manifest>";
var msg2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Manifest><Header><Version>3.2</Version><AccountNumber/><PackageCount>1</PackageCount><FileCreateDateTime>2020-09-15 15:09</FileCreateDateTime><TimeZone>GMT</TimeZone><Filename>MANIFEST-0009-123455678.XML</Filename></Header><Package><ProductDescriptionURL/><FTA/><Item/></Package></Manifest>";

var xdoc1 = XDocument.Parse(msg1);
var xdoc2 = XDocument.Parse(msg2);

xdoc1.Root.Add(xdoc2.Root.Elements("Package"));

var pc = xdoc1.Root.Element("Header").Element("PackageCount");
pc.Value = xdoc1.Root.Elements("Package").Count().ToString();

System.Console.WriteLine(xdoc1);
```

Note that this is only to give you an idea how to solve your problem and it is not stable enough to use in a production environment.

Edit:
I've made a VB console project in Visual studio and got it running

```
Sub Main()
        Dim msg1 As String = "<Manifest><Header><Version>3.2</Version><AccountNumber/><PackageCount>2</PackageCount><FileCreateDateTime>2020-09-15 15:09</FileCreateDateTime><TimeZone>GMT</TimeZone><Filename>MANIFEST-0009-123455678.XML</Filename></Header><Package><ProductDescriptionURL/><FTA/><Item/></Package><Package><ProductDescriptionURL/><FTA/><Item/></Package></Manifest>"
        Dim msg2 As String = "<Manifest><Header><Version>3.2</Version><AccountNumber/><PackageCount>1</PackageCount><FileCreateDateTime>2020-09-15 15:09</FileCreateDateTime><TimeZone>GMT</TimeZone><Filename>MANIFEST-0009-123455678.XML</Filename></Header><Package><ProductDescriptionURL/><FTA/><Item/></Package></Manifest>"

        Dim xdoc1 As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(msg1)
        Dim xdoc2 As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(msg2)

        'add all childs under the tag root that have the name Package to the first doc.
        xdoc1.Root.Add(xdoc2.Root.Elements("Package"))

        'find in the xml tree the element header and from there the element PackageCount
        Dim pc As XElement = xdoc1.Root.Element("Header").Element("PackageCount")
        'alter the value from packagecount with the result of the count of elements named package
        pc.Value = xdoc1.Root.Elements("Package").Count().ToString()

    End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @martjin, Thanks for your answer. However, I have absolutely no knowledge of C# or XML. Could you explain to me what your C# code does so maybe I can search for an equivalent VBA portion of it.